# Error with dependencies when installing new module

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install a new module:

```
npm install --save react-trello
```

But getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/tj/react-click-outside.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I found that `react-click-outside` is a module dependecy on this package.json, but I can do nothing to change, etc.

```
  "dependencies": { ... "react-click-outside": "tj/react-click-outside", ... }
```

This module exists and I can install separately if I try

```
 npm install react-click-outside
```

but It does have no effect when installing the original package.

---

The original lib site https://github.com/rcdexta/react-trello

What can I do?

Comment: Idk how that dependency works, but It appears to be wrong ""tj/react-click-outside""

Comment: You most probably don't have `git` installed on your pc.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I didn't understand that error message, but now it is more clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Molda says in comment, the problem is GIT was not installed.